# How do I perform an FFT on a .wav file?

Tags: fourier-analysis, sound

I've been trying all day to figure out how to do this. I have been able to import the data without any problem and have been able to also plot just the data. However, I keep getting error messages whenever I am trying to do anything with the FFT and I don't know why nothing is happening. All I am trying to do is plot the Fourier Transform so that I can see which frequencies are playing at different amplitudes.

This is what I've done to get the file in.

```
signal = Import["C:\\Users\\Joshua\\Downloads\\Sound Samples\\INSTRUMENTS single \samples\\horns and brass\\bachtrumpet_d4.wav", "Data"];
```

I can plot it just fine

```
ListPlot[signal, Joined -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

and then I can get the Fourier Transform without any problem (and I have tried multiple methods)
This is the easy method

```
dft = Fourier[signal]
```

But then there's a problem with attempting to plot it

```
In[9]:= ListLinePlot[Part[dft, 1 ;; 20000], PlotRange -> Full]

During evaluation of In[9]:= Part::take: Cannot take positions 1 through 
20000 in {{-7.03996+0. I,0.255089 +0.109254 I,0.153395 +0.137607 I,0.101421 
+0.108852 I,<<44>>,0.00897083 -0.0093402 I,-0.0446355+0.0773417 I,
<<127950>>},{-1.57903+0. I,<<49>>,<<127950>>}}. >>

During evaluation of In[9]:= ListLinePlot::lpn: {{-7.03996+0. I,0.255089 
+0.109254 I,0.153395 +0.137607 I,0.101421 +0.108852 I,<<44>>,0.00897083 
-0.0093402 I,-0.0446355+0.0773417 I,<<127950>>},{-1.57903+0. I,<<49>>,
<<127950>>}}[[<<1>>]] is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers. >>

During evaluation of In[9]:= ListLinePlot::lpn: {{-7.03996+0. I,0.255089 
+0.109254 I,0.153395 +0.137607 I,0.101421 +0.108852 I,<<44>>,0.00897083 
-0.0093402 I,-0.0446355+0.0773417 I,<<127950>>},{-1.57903+0. I,<<49>>,
<<127950>>}}[[<<1>>]] is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers. >>

Out[9]= Out[9]
```

Then I tried this more complicated method that I've used for previous examples and was able to get good results with it.

```
n = 5000;
DiscreteFourier[data_] := 
Module[{ft = Abs[Fourier[data[[All, 2]]]]}, 
datanew = RotateRight[ft, Quotient[Length[ft], 2]]; 
freq[t_] := 
With[{tau = t[[2]] - t[[1]], n = Length[t]}, 
Table[-tau/2 + i/(n tau), {i, 0, n - 1}]]; 
Take[Transpose[{freq[data[[All, 1]]], 
 RotateRight[ft, Quotient[Length[data], 1]]}], 
Round[Length[ft]/2]]]
```

But then when I even attempt to just put the wav file into this program, I get an endless amount of error messages.

One thing I have also tried doing to no avail is shortening the amount of data being analyzed

```
localizedtimedata = Table[signal[[j]], {j, 10000, 10100}];
```

I can do the same thing with this data set as I can do with the other data set, meaning plot just the data, but not anything with the Transform unfortunately.

If anybody could help me with this I would be extremely grateful. I need to do this kind of analysis for a lot of files.

Comment: If you look at the error messages carefully, you'll see that you were trying to plot *complex* numbers. Take the magnitude, or phase, or something before plotting.

Comment: `Periodogram@Audio["file.wav"]` should work in Mathematica 11.0 or later.

Comment: This Periodogram command works perfectly for what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Assume you use Mathematica 11.

```
a = Audio[File["ExampleData/car.mp3"]]
Column[{AudioPlot[a, ImageSize -> Medium], Spectrogram[a, ImageSize -> Medium]}]
```

[image]

Verify this use *Adobe Audition cc*.
First one is samples of Audio,and the second is the [STFT](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiY6-_hp7_UAhVBrpQKHWakCTcQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen%2Ewikipedia%2Eorg%2Fwiki%2FShort-time_Fourier_transform&usg=AFQjCNGjIznw7Lem6ZURwI1_nW3ZxCUxsg) of audio.

[image]

And `Periodogram` is useful when you want to look at some position in audio.

For example you want to see the fourier data in 3.8s.

[image]

You can use this code to generate a audio that center in 3.8s

```
(*length of data:1024*)
aNew = AudioTrim[a, {3.8 - 512/QuantityMagnitude@AudioSampleRate[a], 
                     3.8 + 512/QuantityMagnitude@AudioSampleRate[a]}]
```

And use this to perform a 1-dim fourier on this 1024-len data.

```
Periodogram[AudioData[aNew], 1024, 1024, BlackmanHarrisWindow, 
            SampleRate -> QuantityMagnitude@AudioSampleRate[aNew], 
            Ticks -> {Range[0, 22000, 1000], Range[0, -160, -20]}, TicksStyle -> Italic, 
            AspectRatio -> 1/5, AxesLabel -> {"Hz", "dB"}, 
            ImageSize -> 900, Background -> Black, 
            PlotStyle -> Green, AxesStyle -> White]
```

[image]

And you can see the two plot are exactly the same.

Comment: please, let me know what application are you using? Thanks!

Comment: @joseluisbz Adobe Audition